# Emacs: How to configure Emacs for iPython, pylint and autocompletion support?

Tags: python, emacs, ipython, emacs24

I am an intermediate Python programmer that uses Eclipse with the Pydev plugin. 
Now I plan to switch to Emacs to speed up coding. I am struggling with the Emacs configuration
and want to add support for iPython, pylint and Python auto-completion. I installed Emacs24.2.

- **How can I add iPython, Python auto-completion and pylint to my Emacs24.2?**
- **Can you additionally recommend a tutorial or howto?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much everything can be found from the [emacswiki page for python](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs)

As for setting it up, there are plenty of videos on youtube.